# Is a finitely generated extension of a real closed field also real closed?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $\widetilde{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the field of real algebraic numbers, and consider $\widetilde{\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)$. My question: is $\widetilde{\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)$ a real closed field?

Bonus karma points if you can say something about the general claim: Every finitely generated field extension of a real closed field is also real closed.

Thanks!

Comment: No to both. Characterization 5 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) and a basic understanding of Galois theory should quickly demystify both questions.

Comment: The general claim is false, and $\widetilde{\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If your field were real-closed, then it would contain $\sqrt[3]{\pi}$. It it did, then $\pi$ would be algebraic.